# Python multiprocessing pool inside a class

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

I want to run a multiprocessing pool job inside a class's function like that:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

class FindCloasestLocation(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0.
        self.country = ''
        self.city = ''

    def CompareCities(self,location,row):
        print 'ss:',row
        score = self.ComparePhrases(location,row[10])
        return [score,row[5],row[10]]

    def CompareResults(self,inputs):
        score,country,city = inputs
        print 'sc:',score

        if score> self.score:
            self.score = score
            self.country = country
            self.city = city

    def get(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('ws1', type=str, required=True, help="Word set 1 cannot be blank!", action='append')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        location = ' '.join(args['ws1'])
        print 'location:',location,'--',len(df)
        score = 0.
        country = ''
        city = ''
        if len(location)>1:
            try:
                pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
                for i in df.index:
                    pool.apply_async(self.CompareCities,(location,df.ix[i],), callback = self.CompareResults)
                pool.close()
                pool.join()
                return {'score':self.score,'country':self.country,'city':self.city}

            except:
                print 'none!'
                return None
        return None
    def ComparePhrases(self,p1,p2):
        return fuzz.ratio(p1,p2)
```

The problem is that the functions CompareCities and CompareResults are not being called and the score value never updated... Any idea?

Comment: Try passing an `error_callback` function as per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async). Maybe it's never being called because errors are being raised.

Comment: I did add pool.apply_async(self.CompareCities,(location,df.ix[i],), callback = self.CompareResults, error_callback = self.Err) where self.Err has a simple print 'ok' but nothing happened

Comment: Where does `df` come from ?

Comment: df is a global dataframe (define 'global df')